# Best replacement for font tag in html

Tags: css, html, tags, display

Since the `font` tag in HTML is being deprecated in HTML5 (and I understand why) is there a clean solution for applying certain attributes and styles to only *portions* of a paragraph text? I'm using JavaScript to parse an XML file that relies on the fact that the `font` tag allows portions of wrapping text to be formatted using class-based CSS. I realize the "anchor" (`a`) tag could also be used for this purpose, but that way seems very backwards and unnatural.

**EDIT**

When I asked this question (a couple years ago now) I was failing to understand that every DOM element falls into a [`display`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) category, the two primary categories being:

- `block` - insists on taking up its own row
- `inline` - falls in line with other `inline` elements or text

HTML offers two generic container elements, each of which by default adheres to one of these display values; `div` for `block` display, and `span` for `inline` display.

The `span` element is the perfect way to designate a certain chunk of text and give it a unique style or ID because you can wrap it around part of a larger paragraph without breaking the selected contents into a new row.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `span` tag would be the best way.

Although inline CSS is typically not recommended, here is an example:

```
<p>
This is my <span style="font-weight:bold">paragraph</span>.
</p>
```

`span` and `div` are similar, but the `div` tag is a block element, so it will cause line-breaks.  `span` is an inline tag that can be used inline with your text.

Comment: Another good reason to use ```span``` besides ```strong```, ```b``` or ```i``` tags (which are inline tags too) is the fact that these elements are semantically used for enphasis, and should not be used for "random" text portions.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately, I haven't used the span tag much, hence why it wasn't even on my "radar" so to speak. Thanks!

Comment: However, `<font>` does one great thing that `<span>` can't (although you folks might find it horrible): It can straddle `<p>` elements – like this: `<p>first paragraph where <font style="color:blue;">blue text starts, followed by</p><p>second paragraph, where blue text </font> ends.</p>`.  If there are a lot of paragraphs, this is kind of handy. I guess there is no replacement for that?

Comment: That is odd behavior: https://codepen.io/aplocher/pen/ZEYvmav - I'm not sure if there is a way to make span behave the same way as the font is behaving in this example...

Comment: This answer explains a little bit about why `<span>` doesn't work when wrapped around a `<p>`.  It doesn't go into details about why the `<font>` tag DOES work, but I believe font is deprecated in HTML5.  It could just be one of the quirky pre-html5 rendering behaviors... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371706/tag-p-inside-a-span-doesnt-apply-css-style

Comment: Yes, `<font>` is indeed deprecated, that was the premise of this thread (see original question above). And `<span>` will never work like `<font>` does, for the reasons outlined in the cited answer. I get why people want HTML to be tidy, with no enclosed elements having closing tags lagging after the closing tags of enclosing elements. But `<font>` has a kind of rogue beauty to it :)

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<span class="yourstyle">
Text in your style
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.yourstyle {
            color: red;
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use a `<span>` tag

```
<p>here is your paragraph text and it goes on and on and on..... and now 
lets start some <span>formatted text.</span> here is another<span>section 
of formatted text</span> here is unformatted text<p>
```

you can either do inline styles such as `<span style="color: #000000; font-family: calibri, arial, helvetica;">`  or you can just apply a class to your span, like `<span class="textformat1"` and `<span class="textformat2">`. then just apply different css rules based on the class.

```
.textformat1 {
    color: red;
}
.textformat2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Always use css files to hold your code which will be considered "universal" for each element you set. When you want to set for a specific, lets say `<span>` element. You would do just as Adam Plocher said above, use the `style=""` attribute for the `<span>`element.