# Tag p inside a span doesn't apply css style

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with styles. My code is something like this:

```css
.grey {
  color:grey; 
}
```

```html
<span class="grey">
   <p align="justify"><b>Text</b></p>
</span>

<span class="grey">
  Text 2
</span>
```

"Text" appears black, while "Text 2" appears grey. I've tried using a div instead of span, but doesn't work. (I've read that span -> p isn't allowed)

PS: (It works locally with Firefox, but when I'm checking it on the iPad (this is for an iPad app), it doesn't).

Is there a way to force p to apply the style of the span?.

Comment: span is an neutral inline-block element that can contain only text or inline/inline-block elements. .use a neutral div instead to start with a valid code. Then apply your css :)

Comment: What do you mean with a Neutral div?  I've tried div -> p  and it didn't work either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<span>` is *inline level* element, it cannot be placed around a `<p>` element because Paragraphs `<p>` is *block level* element. The rule is that *block* level elements can contain any number of *inline or block* elements. *Inline* level elements can only contain  *inline* elements.

Your HTML should be the following and it'll work: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/RENbN/

```
<div class="grey">
   <p align="justify"><b>Text</b></p>
</div>

<span class="grey">
  Text 2
</span>
```

For more information regarding *inline* and *block* elements see:

- [display:inline vs display:block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099030/displayinline-vs-displayblock)
- http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

If you are still seeing "Text" in black is mostly because there is some CSS selector that has higher specificity and is overriding your `.grey` selector.

Comment: You might want to reread the first affirmation as it's contradicted by the second ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another walkaround I found that works ( best solution is to change span for div) , add in CSS:

```
.grey p 
 {
    color: gray;
 }
```

This will work too.