# JS/HTML onblur runs only once

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having an issue with a college assignment regarding data validation using JS.  I have set the fields to trigger validation onblur and everything works except my code for making sure the password and password verification works.  Once the verification function goes to != it appears the onblur doesn't run again when the field is exited.

I have extracted the code here.  Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

```js
function PVVal() {
  var pwTest = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
  var pwVerify = document.getElementsByName("passwordVerify")[0].value;
  //trim whitespace
  pwTest = pwTest.trim();
  pwVerify = pwVerify.trim();
  if (pwTest != pwVerify) {
    document.getElementById("PVMsg").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>Passwords do not match</font>";
    PVCheck = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementbyId("PVMsg").innerHTML = "";
    PVCheck = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="Password">Password: <span id="PWMsg"></span>
            </label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" onblur="PWVal()" />

<label for="passwordVerify">Verify your Password: <span id="PVMsg"></span>
            </label>
<input type="password" name="passwordVerify" placeholder="Enter in your Password again" onBlur="PVVal()" />
```

Comment: Your function is `PVVal` but you call it `PWVAL` in first input. `document.getElementbyId` needs to be `document.getElementById`. What's the console output?

Comment: You have two typos in your script

Answer (score 0):

I found 4 typos around the naming of `PWVal`, `getElementById` and `onblur`. After fixing those typos, the snippet appears to work as shown below. The validation works properly when exiting the field.

Additionally, it's worth noting to check the console first when experiencing errors like this in the future. The incorrect function names will be called out there and start you down the right path for troubleshooting.

```js
function PWVal() {
  var pwTest = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
  var pwVerify = document.getElementsByName("passwordVerify")[0].value;
  //trim whitespace
  pwTest = pwTest.trim();
  pwVerify = pwVerify.trim();
  if (pwTest != pwVerify) {
    document.getElementById("PVMsg").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>Passwords do not match</font>";
    PVCheck = 0;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("PVMsg").innerHTML = "";
    PVCheck = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="Password">Password: <span id="PWMsg"></span>
            </label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" onblur="PWVal()" />

<label for="passwordVerify">Verify your Password: <span id="PVMsg"></span>
            </label>
<input type="password" name="passwordVerify" placeholder="Enter in your Password again" onblur="PWVal()" />
```

Comment: Also, `<font>` doesn't exist anymore

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that there is a second function not included in the code calling PWVal to check that the password is the correct length onblur of the password input.  As it was functioning properly I did not include it for brevity.

Comment: For j08691- I'm not a programmer/coder/developer.  The project included HTML and CSS that I was given and told not to edit except as necessary to make calls to the JS and functions.  Without using <font> how would I change the text color from the default for that section?

Comment: @PeterH you could use a span tag with inline styles like this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280303/best-replacement-for-font-tag-in-html

Answer (score 0):

It was PVMsg.  I don't knwo why but I changed the span id="theMess" and everything started working as intended.

Thank you for the assistance.